# Surjectivity Stable under Base Change: Reduction Step

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

I have a question about an argument from Bosch's "Algebraic Geometry and Commutative Algebra" (page 465):

[image]

The aim is to show that the property beeing surjective is preserved under basechangem, therefore if $f: X \to Y$ is a surjective map of schemes and $b: Y'\to Y$ provides a base change then in diagram

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X \times_Y Y' @>{f'}  >> Y' \\
@VVprV  @VVbV  \\
X @>{b}>> Y
\end{CD}
$$

the induced morphism $f':X \times_Y Y' \to Y'$ is also surjective.

The author does some reduction steps:

firstly we reduce $Y$ to a point $y \in Y$ interpretet as one point scheme $y \cong Spec(\kappa(y)) = Spec(K)$ and as $Y'$ it's fiber. In other words $b: Y' \to Spec(K)$ is the base change map. That's ok.

But in the next step the author reduces the base change on $Y$ to a field extension $K'/K$ (or in the scheme language $b: Spec(K')=: Y' \to Spec(K)$).

My question is why the last reduction step can be done without loss of generality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Showing that a morphism of schemes is surjective is equivalent to showing that the fibre over every point is nonempty. So you want to consider the pullback of $f^\prime$ along the map $\text{Spec}(k(y)) \rightarrow Y^\prime$ for every $y \in Y^\prime$. Thus you have the following squares:

[image: tex diagram]

As both squares are pullback squares by definition, the outer square is also a pullback and thus it suffices to show that the pullback of $f$ along $ \text{Spec}(k(y)) \rightarrow Y$ is still surjective as this immediately implies that $\text{Spec}(k(y)) \times_{Y^\prime} (X \times_Y Y^\prime)$ is nonempty, as desired. Combined with the other reduction step you already mentioned, this gives you the claim of the author.